# Allocate memory error in dll called by Java JNA

Tags: java, dll, jvm, jna

I try to integrate DLL using JNA in Java. DLL allocates a lot of memory (~600MB).
Library is compiled to 32 bit version, so I need to use 32 bit JVM.

I've got fatal error from JVM

```
 EXCEPTION_UNCAUGHT_CXX_EXCEPTION (0xe06d7363) at pc=0x772bd928, pid=7976, tid=2444
```

with detailed information

```
siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xe06d7363, ExceptionInformation=0x19930520 0x02dce184 0x6a3853d8
```

and stack

```
Stack: [0x023d0000,0x02dd0000],  sp=0x02dce0d0,  free space=10232k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0xbd928]
C  [MSVCR120D.dll+0x120b86]
C  [MSVCR120D.dll+0x12c2a1]
C  [face_analysis_libD.dll+0x1157dc]  operator new[]+0xc
C  [face_analysis_libD.dll+0xea995]  Mat<float>::setSize+0xa5
C  [face_analysis_libD.dll+0xe904e]  Recognizer::initialize+0x9e
C  [face_analysis_libD.dll+0xb2bf9]  Analyser::initializeAnalyser+0x1c9
```

Application is started with params

```
-Xmx1300m -Xms1300m -Xss10m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=3g -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC
```

Probably the problem is with some memory limits on JVM (library works great with C#). Maybe someone has similar problem and can help mi find solution how to run this library in 32 bit JVM.

Comment: Most likely the amount of memory being requested by your `new[]` operator is too large, and no one is bothering to catch the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

32bit applications are generally restricted to 2GB of virtual address space. Assuming you're on a 64bit windows this can be extended to 4GB if the binary has been built with the `largeaddressaware` flag. I think 32bit java.exe has not, although I haven't tested it myself.

So if the JVM is already eating 1.3G for the heap, additional memory for thread stacks and other non-heap data structures then there is fairly little room left for the dll to make allocations. If it then needs to make a large contiguous allocation this is probably going to fail and throw a C++ exception.

Your options likely are:

- reduce heap size
- get a 64bit version of that library instead
- see if marking the binary as largeaddressaware helps, there are tools to do that

Comment: Reducing maximum heap size to 900m `-Xmx900m` helped for my case. Thanks.